# after TexShop update to 4.68, Preview window is blank gray: no text, nothing

Tags: texshop, preview

I am using Mac OS 10.15.7; yesterday upgraded TexShop to 4.68; after the upgrade TexShop Preview window is blank gray, while there are no errors in the console. If I print this window to Mac OS Preview, I see a normal file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the suppoert of TeXShop?

Comment: MacOS 10.5 "Leopard" was first introduced in 2007 and was succeeded by MacOS 10.6 "Snow Leopard" in 2009. Did you check whether TexShop 4.68 supports MacOS 10.5? A separate thought: Any chance you could update your computer's OS to a somewhat newer version of MacOS?

Comment: @Mensch: sorry, my OS version is 10.15. thanks for the advice , but where do I get the TexShop support?

Comment: I do not know TeXShop, I'm a windows user, but I guess there is a support or support page for TeXShop.